# 'block in initialize' uninitialized constant Testdeck NameError (ruby)

Tags: ruby

```
class Deck
    attr_accessor :all
    def initialize
        @all = [1,2,3]
    end
end

newdeck = Deck.new
puts newdeck.all

class Testdeck
    attr_accessor :cards

    def initialize
        @cards = []
        counter = 0
        ['H','C', 'S', 'D'].product(['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','K','Q','A']).each do |arr|
            @cards << Card.new(arr[0], arr[1])
        end
    end
end
zen = Testdeck.new
puts zen.cards.pop
```

This code is giving me: 'block in initialize'  uninitialized constant Testdeck NameError

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Please review these question asking guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: its indented properly in the edit screen, I'm not sure why it is loading like that on the page

Comment: where is your `Car` class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has no clue what a Card is; the error message you're getting is not an `uninitialized constant Testdeck` error but an `uninitialized constant Testdeck::Card` error, where the `::` indicates that Ruby is looking inside the Testdeck class for the Card class (not that you need to put it there, Ruby just looks there first).

You need to define the Card class somewhere, and make its constructor take in a string and an integer.

Comment: I'm not sure why that didn't occur to me originally haha. Thanks Eli.